# Unable to click IMDB 'Load More' button using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape user reviews from the IMDB website using selenium. To load more reviews, I instantiated a click event which clicks the "load more" button on the review page . The issue is that the button gets clicked on the review pages of some movies but it does not work on review pages of other movies.

To give an example, the code given below works when the button is to be clicked on the "Iron Man" user review webpage but on the webpage of "Armageddon", it gives the error: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ipl-load-more__button"}

I find this a bit odd because the web element is the same and so if it works on one page, it should work for all the pages. However, I am not able to resolve this issue.

Here is the code which instantiates the click event:

```
def extend_page(wd): # wd is the webdriver
    count = 20
    while(count>0):
        button = wd.find_element_by_class_name('ipl-load-more__button')
        button.click()
        wd.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
        time.sleep(3)
        new_height = wd.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
        prev_height = new_height
        count-=1
    page = wd.page_source
    return page
```

I have tried different methods for instantiating the click event such as find_element_by_name and find_element_by_xpath. I also tried both implicit and explicit wait to give some time for the webpage to load but to no avail.
Can anyone please tell me what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I tried `driver.find_element_by_id("load-more-trigger").click()` command on both the review pages [ironman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/reviews?ref_=tt_urv) and [Armageddon](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120591/reviews?ref_=tt_ql_3) it works on both the pages and new reviews are also loaded as expected without the error you mentioned.

Comment: @JB, I tried the method you mentioned but I am still getting the same error on the Armageddon webpage.